# Page_Load method doesn't execute

Tags: c#, asp.net

The `Page_Load` method is not executed. This is the List page:

```
 <a href="frm_Vacation_Edit.aspx?ApplyCode=<%#Eval("ProcessApplyCode")%>&VerCode=<%#Eval("ProcessVersion")%>">
     <%# (this.AspNetPager1.CurrentPageIndex - 1) * this.AspNetPager1.PageSize + Container.DataItemIndex + 1%></a>
```

this is the Edit page to receive transmission value

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BandData();
        }
    }
```

But the `Page_Load` Method is never executed. Is this the cache problem?

Comment: Do you mean that it doesn't get invoked?

Comment: To Edit page, the Page_Load does not perform. It doesn't get invoked.

Comment: How do you say it is not perform?

Comment: in order for tags like <%# to work, you have to make dataBinding on the control namingcontainer. Why don't you use <%= instead?

Comment: I think more code outside of what you are doing is required.  It may be that the aspx you are visiting doesn't reference the code behind the page_load() exists in.  Also, have you enabled auto event wire up?

Comment: Can you post the very first line of your aspx page, that has page directive?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` and run it in the debugger. (Make SURE that it's not being executed, as opposed to a problem with your data binding that causes it to appear that way.)

Comment: Is autoevent wireup true or false? ref: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/02/17/inside-autoeventwireup.aspx

Comment: Ah, I see you already found an answer, you might want to mark Kai's answer as an answer.

Comment: Ok,can I send a private letter to Kai?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody can answer if this is a cache problem or not, but you can test it yourself with the debugger or for instance, with a `Label` control which shows a time stamp. Every time the page is refreshed, it should show another time stamp.

From my experience, `Page_Load` will always be invoked. In 5 years of ASP.NET development, I never had the problem that it is not.

Comment: I want to ask next,  how to clean the page caching?